# Flutter: Zooming and overlaying CustomPainter onto high resolution image

Tags: flutter, graphics

I have an application that loads up a high resolution image into an InteractiveViewer and then allows the user to draw over the top (also inside the interactive viewer).  The information drawn is then saved into a database.  This all works fine, I can zoom in and out and everything matches correctly (in terms of the positions of the lines drawn and the underlying image), I just have to scale the line thicknesses to match the transformation controller for the interactive viewer.

But what I've noticed is that if I resize the window I'm drawing into (it's a Windows application),  the position of the drawn elements do not match up to the image correctly.  This is because the x,y positions I have recorded are actually relative to the window, not to the image contents (which is 5000x4000)

If I try and use the TransformationController to work out how to correct the local position of the cursor relative to the image contents, it doesn't work.  It all comes out as if the AssetImage I've loaded up has been resized to fit to the Window.

This is what the build looks like:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerHover: _pointerHover,
      onPointerMove: _pointerMove,
      onPointerDown: _pointerDown,
      onPointerUp: _pointerUp,
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        minScale: 0.5,
        maxScale: 20,
        scaleFactor: 400,
        transformationController: _tController,
        child: Container(
          Stack(
            children: [...myOutlines.map((outline) => PathContainer(outline)),
                       Image.asset(widget.imageFilename)
                      ]
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }
```

The imageFilename is an asset which is 5000x4000 pixels, the myOutlines is a List<List>, each List is passed to a PathContainer which is a Widget that draws a set of lines from the list of offsets in CustomPainter.

The _pointer(Hover, Move, Down, Up) functions get and store the various pointer events into the myOutlines array...

```
  void _pointerMove(PointerMoveEvent event) {
    Offset localPoint = _tController
        .toScene(event.position - Offset(0, AppBar().preferredSize.height));

    print("eventPosition = ${event.position} localPoint = $localPoint");
```

In _pointerMove the localPoint and event.position are only ever in the window coordinate system (i.e. somewhere inside my 1920x1080 window (minus some borders)).  But I would rather store the original image coordinate (somewhere in the 5000,4000 system) without actually having to do the conversion myself...

To me this looks like AssetImage is automatically scaling the image into the 1920x1080 window and the Interactive Viewer is only zooming into this window.  I'm unsure whether I've lost the detail of the original 5000x4000 image or not.

I was expecting anything inside the interactive viewer to be working at the higher resolution coordinate system (5000x4000) but this does not seem to be the case.  I've tried to force the image width/height to 5000x4000 but that also doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: if it is scaled then remove it (I mean remove `Image.asset`) and paint the image as it is inside your `CustomPainter`, that way you have the full control on what and where is drawn

Comment: but honestly if you use `SizedBox(width: 5000, height: 4000, ...)` I don't see any reason why your image would be scaled

Comment: I believe a SizedBox would be limited to the size of the parent though, so it does make sense from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

So, for others with this problem, I found it by reading through the implementation of InteractiveViewer.

There is a property 'constrained' which defaults to true and applies the normal size constraints to the child.  What this means is that normally if you wanted to display an image it would resize the child to fit into the parent.  But in this situation, I don't want it to do that, but leave it as 4000x5000 and allow me to pan and zoom around the image.  Took me a few hours writing my own version of InteractiveViewer to actually read the code and then happened across the property!